# sql query for last 2 records(Dates) per id

Tags: mysql

I want to do a single `SELECT` query that returns the latest 2 records (ordered by Date ) for each ID. For each given ID, the Date values **are not always unique**, so I have to deal with it (look at ID = 1, I want to get only 2 records for it, although it has 2 records from the same date...)

For example, for this table:

```
+------+------------+-------+
|  ID  |    Date    | Value |
+------+------------+-------+
|   1  | 2010       |   33  |
|   1  | 2009       |   23  |
|   1  | 2009       |   41  |
|   1  | 2003       |   55  |
|   1  | 2003       |   24  |
|   2  | 2009       |   52  |
|   2  | 2008       |   23  |
|   2  | 2007       |   39  |
|   2  | 2006       |   22  |
|    
|    
|  ... |    ...     |  ...  |
+------+------------+-------+
```

I would expected to receive:

```
+------+------------+-------+
|  ID  |    Date    | Value |
+------+------------+-------+
|   1  | 2010       |   33  |
|   1  | 2009       |   23  |
|   2  | 2009       |   52  |
|   2  | 2008       |   23  |
|  ... |    ...     |  ...  |
+------+------------+-------+
```

I'm using this script:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date >= IFNULL((SELECT Date
                      FROM MyTable AS T2
                      WHERE T2.ID = MyTable.ID
                      ORDER BY Date DESC
                      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2),
                     0)
```

How can I display the needed result?

Comment: thanks for your quick respond! 
but can i sovle this question without using variables?
can i find a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could use variables for that, which keep track of the `id` of the previous record and the record number within the partition of same `id` values.

For that to work, you first make sure you have an ordered result set, and then assign these two variables their values as the records are processed in that order:

```
select id, date, value
from (
        select   *
        from     mytable
        order by id, date desc
    ) ordered,
    (select @rn := -1, @id := -1) init
where if(@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1, if(@id := id, 1, 1)), @rn, @rn) < 3;
```

The `if` construct is used to evaluate an expression, and then to evaluate something else depending on whether that first expression is considered false or true. In those expressions there are sometimes assignments made.

Comment: thanks for your quick respond! but can i sovle this question without using variables? can i find a simpler solution?

Comment: No that is not possible, since your table has no unique id column. If it would have, then it would be possible, but with a query that would be several times slower than this one.

Comment: NB: when I say *unique id*, I don't refer to the column you have called `ID`, but any column that could serve as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

First, use a `SELECT` statement to get all the rows in `ORDER` along with `count` for each id, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, `date`, `value`, 
@count := IF(@previous = id, @count + 1, 1) AS `count`, @previous := id  
FROM test, (SELECT @previous := 0, @count := 1) a
ORDER BY id ASC, `date` DESC;
```

Once done, you can wrap it into another select and get only those rows with count <= 2, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT id, `date`, `value`, 
 @count := IF(@previous = id, @count + 1, 1) AS `count`, @previous := id  
 FROM test, (SELECT @previous := 0, @count := 1) a
 ORDER BY id ASC, `date` DESC
) b
WHERE b.count <= 2;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb7e3/6/0)**.

Comment: thanks for your quick respond! but can i sovle this question without using variables? can i find a simpler solution?

Comment: A simple answer is no. What you are trying to do here is to apply `limit` per group and that is something MySQL doesn't support out of the box.